# How to convert SFZ and GIG soudfonts to SF2 under Linux?

Tags: linux, sound-font

Under LMMS Linux I can only handle SF2 soundfonts, while a number of free soundfonts come in either GIG or SFZ format. I'd need to convert those two into SF2 format.
How to?

Comment: You can use SFZ in Linux: https://www.linuxsampler.org/sfz/  SFZ is superior to SF2 if I understand correctly.

Comment: LMMS doesn't support linuxsampler yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Polyphone](http://www.polyphone.fr/) is cross-platform and will open sf2, sf3, sfz, and sfArk, and will save to sf2 or export to sfz or sf3.  It's sf2-centric, though, so it doesn't support some features like sfz's round-robin.

[Plogue sforzando](https://www.plogue.com/products/sforzando/) is Windows (WINE?) or OS X, and will convert sfz to sf2, though the conversion did not work well for one thing I tested.  Polyphone did a better job.

Comment: Polyphone's conversion to SF2 can fail (volume of hammer sounds too loud from a piano , etc.), and neither software supports GIG.